# Share Images on Facebook, under a Business Page

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-share

I'm using Facebook SDK in order to use sharing feature; and I'm able to share an image using below code snippet,

```
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(sharePhoto)
                .setPageId("businessPageId")
                .setShareHashtag(shareHashTag)
                .build();
```

It's working fine, but the thing is, this image goes under the user's news feed, but I want this to go under my business page's feed. Is there anyway I can achieve that?